# ACE.OLEDB.12.O connection not open

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Dim Dutycon As OleDbConnection
    Dim DutyAdo As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DutyCmd As OleDbCommandBuilder
    Dim DutyI As New Integer
    Dim DutyTab As New DataTable
    Dim DutyRow As DataRow

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Duty_EmployeeTableAdapter.Fill(Me._Duty_DatabaseDataSet1.Duty_Employee)
        Dutycon = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Datasource=Duty-Database.accdb; Presist security info=false;")
        DutyAdo = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Duty_Employee", Dutycon)
        DutyCmd = New OleDbCommandBuilder(DutyAdo)

        Try
            Dutycon.Open()
            MsgBox("Database opened")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Database Not connected -- -.. " + ex.Message)
        End Try
        DutyAdo.Fill(DutyTab)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DutyTab
    End Sub

    Private Sub Duty_EmployeeBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Duty_EmployeeBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.Duty_EmployeeBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me._Duty_DatabaseDataSet1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Cmd_Add_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Cmd_Add.Click
        Dutycon.Open()

        DutyRow = DutyTab.NewRow
        DutyRow("Emp_No") = TextBox1.Text
        DutyRow("Emp_Name") = TextBox2.Text
        DutyRow("Emp_salary") = TextBox3.Text
        DutyTab.Rows.Add(DutyRow)
        DutyAdo.Update(DutyTab)

        MsgBox("New Record added", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Record Stored")

        Dutycon.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Connection () can't open

> Could not find installeble ISAM

I have Ms-Office 2007  (Access) and connect to VB.net through "ACE.OLEDB.12.0"

Comment: if you're using `Data source=Duty-Database.accdb` like that without a path, then can you tell us where you placed that file?

Comment: btw it's too early to use try-catch now before you make sure your code has no errors, you're only testing now, let your app crash and give you an error it will even indicate where your error is..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have use vb.net. I can't open oldeb.ace.12.0 connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58003937/i-have-use-vb-net-i-cant-open-oldeb-ace-12-0-connection)

Comment: I Googled "could not find installable isam access" and got 20,600 results. Why not check a few of them.